# R: median of specific value rows

Tags: r

I need to get a median value of rows based on another column (SEQ). Let me explain You on base of the sample data:

```
data <- structure(list(DATUM = structure(c(1335558400, 1335558400, 1335558400, 
                                           1335558400, 1335562429, 1335562429, 1335562429, 1335562429, 1335562429, 
                                           1335562429, 1335562429, 1335562429, 1335562429, 1335562429, 1335562429, 
                                           1335567274, 1335567274, 1335567274, 1335567274, 1335567274, 1335567274, 
                                           1335567274, 1335567274, 1335567274, 1335567274, 1335567274, 1335681543, 
                                           1335681543, 1335681543, 1335681543), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
                                           )), CHGNR = c(200028, 200028, 200028, 200028, 200029, 200029, 
                                                         200029, 200029, 200029, 200029, 200029, 200029, 200029, 200029, 
                                                         200029, 200029, 200029, 200029, 200029, 200029, 200029, 200029, 
                                                         200029, 200029, 200029, 200029, 200057, 200057, 200057, 200057
                                           ), SEQ = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
                                                      2L
                                          ), PROBE = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                                                       2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 
                                                     2
                                          ), METHODE = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a",
                                                         "a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b"
                                          ),MITTELWERT = c(2.5,1.67, 0, 0, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                             0, 5, 0, 0.833333333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.5, 1, 0, 0, 
                                                             0, 0.5, 0.666666666666667,1, 0, 0)
                       ), .Names = c("DATUM", "CHGNR", "SEQ","PROBE","METHODE", "MITTELWERT"), 
                  row.names = c(NA,30L), class = "data.frame")
```

So the data looks like that:

```
                 DATUM  CHGNR SEQ PROBE METHODE MITTELWERT
1  2012-04-27 22:26:40 200028   1     1       a  2.5000000
2  2012-04-27 22:26:40 200028   1     1       a  1.6700000
3  2012-04-27 22:26:40 200028   1     1       b  0.0000000
4  2012-04-27 22:26:40 200028   1     1       b  0.0000000
5  2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   1     1       a  0.5000000
6  2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   1     1       a  0.3333333
7  2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.5000000
8  2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.0000000
9  2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.0000000
10 2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       b  0.0000000
11 2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       b  0.0000000
12 2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       b  0.0000000
13 2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       b  5.0000000
14 2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.0000000
15 2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.8333333
16 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     2       a  0.0000000
17 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     2       a  0.0000000
18 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     2       a  0.0000000
19 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     2       a  0.0000000
20 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     2       b  0.0000000
21 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     3       b  0.5000000
22 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     3       b  1.0000000
23 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     3       b  0.0000000
24 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     3       b  0.0000000
25 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     3       b  0.0000000
26 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     3       a  0.5000000
27 2012-04-29 08:39:03 200057   1     1       a  0.6666667
28 2012-04-29 08:39:03 200057   2     2       a  1.0000000
29 2012-04-29 08:39:03 200057   2     2       b  0.0000000
30 2012-04-29 08:39:03 200057   2     2       b  0.0000000
```

I would like to get a **new row** with median of column `MITTELWERT` for each unique `CHGNR` and `METHODE` and ONLY for **SEQ > 1** (+ the first value of the columns `DATUM` and `PROBE`). Therefore in this sample data, it would look like that:

```
                 DATUM  CHGNR SEQ PROBE METHODE MITTELWERT
1  2012-04-27 22:26:40 200028   1     1       a  2.5000000
2  2012-04-27 22:26:40 200028   1     1       a  1.6700000
3  2012-04-27 22:26:40 200028   1     1       b  0.0000000
4  2012-04-27 22:26:40 200028   1     1       b  0.0000000
5  2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   1     1       a  0.5000000
6  2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   1     1       a  0.3333333
7  2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.5000000
8  2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.0000000
9  2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.0000000
10 2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       b  0.0000000
11 2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       b  0.0000000
12 2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       b  0.0000000
13 2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       b  5.0000000
14 2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.0000000
15 2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.8333333
16 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     2       a  0.0000000
17 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     2       a  0.0000000
18 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     2       a  0.0000000
19 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     2       a  0.0000000
20 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     2       b  0.0000000
21 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     3       b  0.5000000
22 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     3       b  1.0000000
23 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     3       b  0.0000000
24 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     3       b  0.0000000
25 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     3       b  0.0000000
26 2012-04-28 00:54:34 200029   3     3       a  0.5000000
27 2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   >1    2       a  0.0000000 #new calculated row with median value for unique CHGNR and METHODE "a"
28 2012-04-27 23:33:49 200029   >1    2       b  0.0000000 #new calculated row with median value for unique CHGNR and METHODE "b"
...
```

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: Are those values for the median correct for the test data you supplied? Because I see zero for median(MITTELWERT) for CHGNR==200029 for both SEQ==a and SEQ==b

Comment: it should be median(MITTELWERT) for CHGNR == 200029 and SEQ > 1 and METHODE == a /or METHODE == b, but Yes you are correct,my bad, i calculated it wrong in this example

Comment: And not to be a stickler, but for data sets where _median_ is different from _mean_ you use of  `Mittelwert=median()` is wrong-- the word would imply `mean()`.

Comment: Hi Dirk, not really. The whole column is actually mean value of a test methode (prufmethode). Median values are there to summaries mean values for seq >1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
out <- data %>% group_by(CHGNR,METHODE) %>% 
                summarise(DATUM=DATUM[1],PROBE=PROBE[1],MITTELWERT=median(MITTELWERT[SEQ>1]),SEQ=">1") %>%
                ungroup %>% filter(!is.na(MITTELWERT)) %>% 
                select(DATUM,CHGNR,SEQ,PROBE,METHODE,MITTELWERT) #%>%
```

We `group_by` both `CHGNR` and `METHODE` to split the rows into groups for each `CHGNR` and `METHODE`. Then `summarise` with `median` to compute the median `MITTELWERT`. Note that `MITTELWERT` is subset by `SEQ>1`. In `summarise`, we also summarize `DATUM` and `PROBE` with their first elements and we set `SEQ` to `">1"`. Finally, we `ungroup`, remove those rows with `NA` and reorder the columns to match the original `data`.

To add the result to `data` as additional rows, we need to change the `SEQ` column to `character`. Then, we can use `bind_rows`.

```
data$SEQ <- as.character(data$SEQ)
out <- bind_rows(data,out)
                 DATUM  CHGNR SEQ PROBE METHODE MITTELWERT
1  2012-04-27 16:26:40 200028   1     1       a  2.5000000
2  2012-04-27 16:26:40 200028   1     1       a  1.6700000
3  2012-04-27 16:26:40 200028   1     1       b  0.0000000
4  2012-04-27 16:26:40 200028   1     1       b  0.0000000
5  2012-04-27 17:33:49 200029   1     1       a  0.5000000
6  2012-04-27 17:33:49 200029   1     1       a  0.3333333
7  2012-04-27 17:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.5000000
8  2012-04-27 17:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.0000000
9  2012-04-27 17:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.0000000
10 2012-04-27 17:33:49 200029   2     2       b  0.0000000
11 2012-04-27 17:33:49 200029   2     2       b  0.0000000
12 2012-04-27 17:33:49 200029   2     2       b  0.0000000
13 2012-04-27 17:33:49 200029   2     2       b  5.0000000
14 2012-04-27 17:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.0000000
15 2012-04-27 17:33:49 200029   2     2       a  0.8333333
16 2012-04-27 18:54:34 200029   3     2       a  0.0000000
17 2012-04-27 18:54:34 200029   3     2       a  0.0000000
18 2012-04-27 18:54:34 200029   3     2       a  0.0000000
19 2012-04-27 18:54:34 200029   3     2       a  0.0000000
20 2012-04-27 18:54:34 200029   3     2       b  0.0000000
21 2012-04-27 18:54:34 200029   3     3       b  0.5000000
22 2012-04-27 18:54:34 200029   3     3       b  1.0000000
23 2012-04-27 18:54:34 200029   3     3       b  0.0000000
24 2012-04-27 18:54:34 200029   3     3       b  0.0000000
25 2012-04-27 18:54:34 200029   3     3       b  0.0000000
26 2012-04-27 18:54:34 200029   3     3       a  0.5000000
27 2012-04-29 02:39:03 200057   1     1       a  0.6666667
28 2012-04-29 02:39:03 200057   2     2       a  1.0000000
29 2012-04-29 02:39:03 200057   2     2       b  0.0000000
30 2012-04-29 02:39:03 200057   2     2       b  0.0000000
31 2012-04-27 17:33:49 200029  >1     1       a  0.0000000
32 2012-04-27 17:33:49 200029  >1     2       b  0.0000000
33 2012-04-29 02:39:03 200057  >1     1       a  1.0000000
34 2012-04-29 02:39:03 200057  >1     2       b  0.0000000
```

Comment: Nice solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

This can be achieved with `library(data.table)`.

```
library(data.table)    
# Create data here ----      
data <- data.table(data) # Converts to data set

crunchedData <- data[SEQ > 1,
               j = .(SEQ = ">1",MITTELWERT = median(MITTELWERT) ),
              by = .(CHGNR,METHODE)]
```

From here you can `rbind` `crunchedData` onto `data` using whatever values of `DATUM` and `PROBE` you like.

If you're not familiar with `data.table`, the first parameter (`i`) takes logic (similar to data frames) which subsets by row. `j` is filled with columnwise operations (where each column can be  referred to by its column name) and `by` (or `k`, if you like) defines the groups to group rows by.

Comment: Thats quite interesting solution, works very well! I am not familiar with data.table package, therefore the solution using dplyr was the right one for me.. Thank You anyways!

Comment: Membership in the _tidyverse_ appears to imply acceptance of its solutions at all cost.

Answer (score 3):

You can compute group median using:

```
library(sqldf)
df1=sqldf("select DATUM,CHGNR,SEQ,PROBE,METHODE, median(MITTELWERT) as MITTELWERT from df where SEQ>1 group by CHGNR,METHODE")
```

You can then do further modification to the dataframe and then do a `rbind`.

```
tail(rbind(df,df1))

               DATUM  CHGNR SEQ PROBE METHODE MITTELWERT
29 2012-04-29 12:09:03 200057   2     2       b          0
30 2012-04-29 12:09:03 200057   2     2       b          0
31 2012-04-28 04:24:34 200029   3     3       a          0
32 2012-04-28 04:24:34 200029   3     3       b          0
33 2012-04-29 12:09:03 200057   2     2       a          1
34 2012-04-29 12:09:03 200057   2     2       b          0
```